# Git: "nothing to commit" at root level, but unmodified files shown as modified in subfolder

Tags: git

I have a strange problem with git. My folder structure is (simplified) like this:

```
  /wte/
  /wte/bib
  /wte/MATLAB
  /wte/MATLAB/lib
  /wte/MATLAB/simdp
```

*These folders (apart the first two) all contain files.*

Now if I do `git status` in `/wte/`:

```
$ git st
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

But if I do `git status` in `/wte/MATLAB/` (or `/wte/bib/`):

```
$ git st
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/lib/XSteam_Matlab_v2.6/X Steam for Matlab.pdf
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/lib/XSteam_Matlab_v2.6/XSteam.m
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/lib/XSteam_Matlab_v2.6/XSteamUS.m
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/simdp/extract_mdp_parallel.m
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/simdp/get_virgin_source_states.m
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/simdp/proj.sublime-project
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/simdp/proj.sublime-workspace
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/simdp/tests/T_get_virgin_source_states.m
#       modified:   ../MATLAB/simdp/tests/run_tests.m
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

These file have not been modified:

```
ost@d-win-1 ~/ba/wte/MATLAB
$ git diff simdp/get_virgin_source_states.m 

ost@d-win-1 ~/ba/wte/MATLAB
$ git diff simdp/extract_mdp_parallel.m 

ost@d-win-1 ~/ba/wte/MATLAB
$ git diff lib/XSteam_Matlab_v2.6/XSteam.m
```

So what is going on here? Any ideas?

*Note that these are not all the files, just some of them...*

Thanks!

System:

- Windows 7 (64 bit)
- Git 1.7.5.1
- Cygwin

Comment: Does /wte/MATLAB/ have its own git repository? That could explain your results.

Comment: No. That was my first thought too, but it doesn't...

Comment: Have you checked your autocrlf settings?

Comment: @StuartCarnie - That doesn't explain why it doesn't report anything in the status for root?

Comment: @StuartCarnie - autocrlf is set to true (because others/I also develop on OSX/unix boxes)

Comment: are they imported as submodules? altough I believe that, that would show up in the root directory if changes occurs :/

Comment: @Sedrik - They are not submodules. This is an entirely basic repo (no submodules, not sub-repos, ...)

Comment: it sounds to me like there's something broken in the internal repo structure. If you have no changes to lose, push your commits, delete your local repo and reclone it?

Comment: @o1iver btw, do you have .gitattributes defined in wte/MATLAB/?

Answer (score 0):

Install normal git from http://git-scm.com/download/win.

I had the same problem, so I just removed cygwin's git and installed a normal one and the problem disappeared.

Comment: note that there are other features that one loses when going to msysgit instead of cygwin git.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is in file-mode. For Windows you should try `git config --global core.fileMode false`. More info [here](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-config.html).